# QGraphicScene redraw on QGraphicItem move

Tags: qt, events, qgraphicsitem, qgraphicsscene

I'm trying to fiddle a bit with a [Qt example](http://www.informit.com/articles/article.aspx?p=1405545&seqNum=4) regarding 2D Graphics.

Basically it is a small diagram editor. In the example, the author explains that the `tracknodes()` function *is used to update the line's endpoints, when the user drags a connected node into a different position*.

This actually does not happen. After looking at the code, I have the feeling it's because there is no event being called after moving the *node* QGraphicItem, in order to update the *link*'s rendering.

I figured I have to find out where and how the *QGraphicItem*'s movement is handled in order to send a *wasDropped* signal (or something like that) to a slot that re-renders the link. Does this make sense?

I'm pretty new to Qt/C++ in general, so I don't have a very clear idea on how to achieve this, does anyone have any pointers he/she could share?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

He seems to be using the [QGraphicsItem::itemChange](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qgraphicsitem.html#itemChange) virtual function to call the `tracknodes()` function which draws the lines. `ItemChange` should be called every time a node is moved. It's called in other cases as well but he only uses it for tracking the movement of the `QGraphicsItem`.

Comment: Actually I figured it out, there was a **ItemSendsGeometryChanges** flag missing in the _node_ cpp. But your answer is correct regarding what I actually asked. +1

Comment: @Jorum Oh, sorry I forgot to mention that you need to set the `ItemSendsGeometryChanges` flag for the `QGraphicsItem` to get those notifications. I'm glad you caught that.